# Flash AS3 Image effect

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying split an image into seperate blocks, which is kind of accomplished using the following tutorial/source ([code here](http://www.riacodes.com/flash/image-appearance-effect-fall-down/)), but it is the wrong way round - how would I adjust the code in order to start on the full image and then break it into pieces?

Original code (courtesy of www.riacodes.com):

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

const COLUMNS:uint=5;
const ROWS:uint=5;

var imagesGrid : Array = new Array();    

var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest("image.jpg"));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);

function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {

    var originalBitmapData:BitmapData = e.target.content.bitmapData;

    var imageWidth : Number  = originalBitmapData.width / COLUMNS;
    var imageHeight : Number = originalBitmapData.height / ROWS;

    for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {

            var imageHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

            var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            image.bitmapData=new BitmapData(imageWidth,imageHeight);
            image.bitmapData.copyPixels(
                                originalBitmapData,
                                new Rectangle(j * imageWidth, i * imageHeight,imageWidth, imageHeight),
                                new Point(0,0));

            imageHolder.addChild(image);

            imageHolder.x= j*imageWidth ;
            imageHolder.y= i*imageHeight ;

            imageHolder.alpha=0;

            imagesGrid.push(imageHolder);
            addChild(imageHolder);

        }
    }
    revealImage();
}

function revealImage():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i <imagesGrid.length; i++){
        var imageGrid:MovieClip = imagesGrid[i] as MovieClip;
        imageGrid.alpha = 1;
        TweenLite.from(imageGrid,.8,{alpha:0,y:-200,delay:i*.1,ease:Back.easeOut});
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change revealImage().

onImageLoaded() takes care of breaking your loaded image into smaller parts. You can actually change the size of the parts by manipulating these:

```
const COLUMNS:uint=5;
const ROWS:uint=5;
```

As shanethehat points out, when the function is complete the images are not visible because 
of the following line, that sets a zero value for the transparency ( max value = 1 )

```
imageHolder.alpha=0;
```

Practically you end up with an Array of Movie Clips , each containing a slice of the main image. 
In revealImage() you can then loop thru this Array and assign random values to both the x & y of each Movie Clip in order to break the main image into pieces.

```
for( var i:int ; i <imagesGrid.length; i++)
{
    var imageGrid:MovieClip = imagesGrid[i];
    imageGrid.alpha = 1;

    // Calculate a random value for x , y
    // Tweak this according to the Fx you're looking for
    var randomX:Number  = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    var randomY:Number  = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

    TweenLite.to(imageGrid, 1, 
      {x:randomX, y:randomY, delay:i*.1,ease:Back.easeOut}});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, change line 38 of the linked code to:

```
imageHolder.alpha=1;
```

This ensures that the parts of your image start off being visible.

Next, change line 52 to:

```
TweenLite.to(imageGrid,.8,{alpha:0,y:-200,delay:i*.1,ease:Back.easeOut});
```

This changes the TweenLite function from `from()` to `to()`, in other words it causes each element to animate *to* the values given in the object.